# Filtering Query Using Timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a query that brigs me all the records between two timestamps stored in my database. 
As I said, in my DB I have 2 attributes (startTime, endTime) as a timestamp. and in my php page there are two input elements that allowed the user to pick out a date formatted as %m/%d/%y

in PHP page I am using the following query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT FROM time_log WHERE 
ticket_user = " . $ticket_user . "AND 
FROM_UNIXTIME( startTime, '%m/%d/%Y' ) >=FROM_UNIXTIME(" . $start . ", '%m/%d/%Y' ) 
AND FROM_UNIXTIME( endTime, '%m/%d/%Y' ) <=FROM_UNIXTIME(" . $end . ", %m/%d/%Y' ");
```

Note: `$start` and `$end` are timestamp variables.

when I submit the form I get nothing. Is there something wrong in it, something needs to update!!?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the data type of `startTime` and `endtime` in DB ?

Comment: timestamp, it is stored like this 1406221200

Comment: if user is selecting the input date as m/d/Y then why to use `FROM_UNIXTIME` to those input values. You can use them directly as a string, just need it for already saved value.

Comment: because the $_POST['start'] is giving me a timestamp like the following 1406221200

Comment: I am storing the $_POST['start'] into $start

Comment: Hmm query looks good, may be its not finding value with the given range. Hard to say without having some data to test these.

Comment: Is the logic of the query is good or there are some wholes(bugs) in it?

Comment: Yes it looks good to me, the only thing you can try using the date format to Y-m-d in the comparison. But your query also looks good.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty _Query looks good???_ **You are not looking close enough**

Comment: I tried something else in Mysql
SELECT *
FROM time_log
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME( starttime, '%m/%d/%Y' ) >= FROM_UNIXTIME( '1410480000', '%m/%d/%Y' )
AND FROM_UNIXTIME( endtime, '%m/%d/%Y' ) <= FROM_UNIXTIME( '1410886800', '%m/%d/%Y' )
AND ticket_user = '85'
it gave me a correct result

Comment: in PHP I tried the following:
$res = mysql_query("SELECT FROM time_log WHERE ticket_user = '" . $ticket_user . "' AND FROM_UNIXTIME(starttime, '%m/%d/%Y' ) >= FROM_UNIXTIME('" . $starttime . "', '%m/%d/%Y' ) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(endtime, '%m/%d/%Y' ) <=FROM_UNIXTIME('" . $endtime . "', %m/%d/%Y' ");
Note that I added the single quote before and after the var name

Comment: Are you missing fields to return in the select?  `Select *` in other words?

Comment: No I just forgot to write it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If valueas stored in database are in timestamp and $start, $end are in timestamp, why do you use FROM_UNIXTIME()? Can't you just compare the timestamps?
Like this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT FROM time_log WHERE 
ticket_user = '" . $ticket_user . "' AND 
startTime >= '" . $start . "' 
endTime <= '" . $end . "');
```

Comment: I tried that solution before I read your answer, you're absolutely right :)

Answer (score 0):

I see at least one thing that would cause a problem, so I suggest you add some checking code after each of your queries like so.

```
$sql = "SELECT FROM time_log 
        WHERE 
          ticket_user = " . $ticket_user . "AND 
          FROM_UNIXTIME( startTime, '%m/%d/%Y' ) >= FROM_UNIXTIME(" . $start . ", '%m/%d/%Y' ) 
          AND FROM_UNIXTIME( endTime, '%m/%d/%Y' ) <= FROM_UNIXTIME(" . $end . ", %m/%d/%Y' "

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $sql;
    die($message);
}
```

This should tell you when you have made an error in your SQL without having to ask a question here.

Comment: You were right I got the following error:

Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM time_log WHERE ticket_user = 85AND FROM_UNIXTIME( starttime, '%m/%d/%Y' ) >' at line 1 Whole query:

Comment: No, because I don't see an error in it, or I can't see an error in it :)

Comment: Change `ticket_user = " . $ticket_user . "AND ` to `ticket_user = " . $ticket_user . " AND` There is no space between the `85` and the `AND`

Comment: I believe this is one mistake but it didn't solve the problem, still got an error
Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM time_log WHERE ticket_user = 85 AND FROM_UNIXTI' at line 1 Whole query:

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM time_log`

Comment: I tried something else in Mysql
SELECT *
FROM time_log
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME( starttime, '%m/%d/%Y' ) >= FROM_UNIXTIME( '1410480000', '%m/%d/%Y' )
AND FROM_UNIXTIME( endtime, '%m/%d/%Y' ) <= FROM_UNIXTIME( '1410886800', '%m/%d/%Y' )
AND ticket_user = '85'
it gave me a correct result

Comment: in PHP I tried the following:
$res = mysql_query("SELECT FROM time_log WHERE ticket_user = '" . $ticket_user . "' AND FROM_UNIXTIME(starttime, '%m/%d/%Y' ) >= FROM_UNIXTIME('" . $starttime . "', '%m/%d/%Y' ) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(endtime, '%m/%d/%Y' ) <=FROM_UNIXTIME('" . $endtime . "', %m/%d/%Y' ");
Note that I added the single quote before and after the var name

Comment: Come on.... Change the PHP code to `SELECT * FROM` SQL has rules, you have to stick to them!